# How to close popup when clicked outside of popup without StaysOpen=false?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

XAML:

```
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox" GotFocus="textBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="textBox_LostFocus"/>
    <Popup x:Name="pop" StaysOpen="True" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=textBox}" >
        <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Some Message"/>
    </Popup>
```

On code behind I currently have:

```
    private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pop.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pop.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

I would like to show the popup while the textbox gets focus and stays until anywhere else is clicked or the textbox loses focus. So StaysOpen=false does not work. After a lot of search I looked up the code of the combobox which is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Popup.cs)

I think the following code is the reason setting StaysOpen=false causes the popup to close when clicked outside of popup. I have no idea how to override this behavior.
The exact link of the following code is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Popup.cs,753e3c23e2428b14) (Comments removed for brevity)

```
private static void OnLostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup popup = sender as Popup;
         if (!popup.StaysOpen)
        {
            PopupRoot root = popup._popupRoot.Value;
            bool reestablishCapture = e.OriginalSource != root && Mouse.Captured == null && MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.GetCapture() == IntPtr.Zero;

            if(reestablishCapture)
            {
                popup.EstablishPopupCapture();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if(Mouse.Captured != root)
                {
                    popup._cacheValid[(int)CacheBits.CaptureEngaged] = false;
                }

                bool newCaptureInsidePopup = Mouse.Captured != null && MenuBase.IsDescendant(root, Mouse.Captured as DependencyObject);
                bool newCaptureOutsidePopup = !newCaptureInsidePopup && Mouse.Captured != root;
                if(newCaptureOutsidePopup && !popup.IsDragDropActive)
                {
                    popup.SetCurrentValueInternal(IsOpenProperty, BooleanBoxes.FalseBox);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I may suggest try putting a breakpoint on your code. Specifically your your eventhandlers textBox_LostFocus and  textBox_GotFocus. If you do, you will realize that when the Popup shows, the lost focus handler will be hit. And the code is setting the IsOpen to false.. Start there...